# Organizing code with common functions, avoiding multiple definition

Tags: cuda

I have two cuda kernels imageFlow() and cornerDetect(), defined in their individual cu files. They share a common global function, convolute1D(), which should rightfully have been in its own cu file as well. I had to place it, the implementation - not just the definition of convolute1D, in a header file convolution.h. This is then included in both cornerDetect.cu and imageFlow.cu, in order to use it from both kernels. This is because everything must be in the "same compilation unit".

Now the problem is that after compilation, convolute1D is actually defined in both imageFlow.obj and in cornerDetect.obj, since the included header had the actual implementation of the function.

This means that the final linker stage conplains about convolute1D being defined multiple times.

One solution would be to always use namespaces, but this that THE solution? It seems more like patching up the problem. I still have the implementation for convolute1D multiple times in the final binary, and what if I have some reason to use the same namespace for both my imageFlow and cornerDetection?

Comment: The first thing I'd try would be to declare convolute1D() as inline, but without a concrete repro and resolution in hand, I'm reluctant to offer that as the "answer."

Answer (score 2):

What about use extern definition?

```
// convolution.h
extern "C" void convolution1D() {
   ...
}

// imageFlow.cu 
extern "C" void convolution1d();

// call the function when you need
convolution1D();
```

Same approach for cornerDetect.cu file.

Comment: They are cuda kernels, which mean that the C linkage is invalid. I should have written __global__ convolute1D(..) to make that point more clear. Sorry about that.

Comment: @joetaicoon I'm missing now. do you have a kernel in a .h?